# Session fails to maintain after page redirect

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have been beating my my head over this.  My code is virtually identical to other projects where this DOES work.  Here is how I do it:

```
session_start();
set_up_session($username);
redirect_to('index.php');
```

And the two functions:

```
 function redirect_to($location=null) {
        if($location!=null) {
        header("Location: {$location}");
        exit;
        }
    }

    function set_up_session($username) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['user_id']=$id;
        $_SESSION['logged_in']=true;
        $_SESSION['username']=$username;
    }
```

if I comment out the redirect and echo any of the `$_SESSION` var's, the var reads correctly.  But after the redirect, the session ends.

This is what's on the next page.

```
<?php if (!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) { ?>

// do stuff  <-- this is what gets shown showing session is no longer active

<?php } else { ?>

<p>Hi, <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></p>


<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure the page you are redirecting to has `session_start()` at the top of the document

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: It's not wrong, it's completely normal. If you want the page to recognize a session then you have to make that page part of the session also. I've edited my answer to stop your error.

Comment: I fixed the header error; but what if I don't want a session started for a guest user? (or will it not harm anything? if no var's are set)

Comment: A guest will not be part of the session if they have not been given session variables through a login system etc.

Comment: Ok, I see what is going on now.  I usually do this with a session `class` and have just cut and pasted it in so often I literally forgot what was going on!  Now doing it that non-OO way, manually, makes me see what I am actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

My first step I would do is try this on the next page:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        echo $_SESSION['username'];
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }
?>
```

I had a problem a posted earlier in dealing with sessions. My resolution to the problem was to set a $_SESSION[]; to a variable. EX:

```
<?php

    $Username = "Guest"; //Set your variable before you actually need it. (This is what fixed my problem) 
    if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
        $Username = $_SESSION['username'];
    }


?>
```

NOTE: You might want to change the if (isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) to instead check for if the username is set. For example:

```
<?php
    $User = "Guest";
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $User = $_SESSION['username'];
    } else {
        //do stuff
    }

?>
```

Also, as stated by the other user, make sure the page you redirect to has a session_start(); function in it. Otherwise, this will not work.

Comment: Hey thanks for your tips; however,  I could not get this working even after all of them...

Comment: On the next page, where you have your code to check if the session is set, do you have "session_start();" right after your <?php tag? If not, that will be the problem.